# SPQuery cause me an error: "One or more field types are not installed properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml

the problem is a CAML query of SPQuery that throw an error: One or more field types are not installed properly
any help please:
it work perfect in U2U CAML
 source code is:

```
   sb.Append("<Where>");
    sb.Append("<Or>");
                            sb.Append("<And>");
                                sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" +   
  ConstVariables.valide_les_destinataires_encodé + "' /><Value    
  Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>");
                                sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
  ConstVariables.envoyer_vers_directeur_encodé + "' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>");
                            sb.Append("</And>");

                            sb.Append("<Or>");
                                sb.Append("<And>");
                                    sb.Append("<And>");
                                        sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
  ConstVariables.valide_les_destinataires_encodé + "' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>");
                                        sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
   ConstVariables.envoyer_vers_directeur_encodé + "' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>");
                                    sb.Append("</And>");
                                    sb.Append("<And>"); 
                                        sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
  ConstVariables.reponse_destinataires_encodé + "' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
  </Eq>");
                                        sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
   ConstVariables.fiche_distribution_prepare_encodé + "' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
  </Eq>");
                                    sb.Append("</And>");
                                sb.Append("</And>");
                                sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + 
  ConstVariables.valid_par_directeur_ca_encodé + "' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>");
                             sb.Append("</Or>");
                        sb.Append("</Or>");

                        sb.Append("</Where>");



   SPView vv = list.Views["Tous les documents"];
            SPQuery squery = new SPQuery();
            squery.Query = sb.ToString();

            vv.Query = squery.Query;
            vv.Update();

            list.Update();
            list.ParentWeb.Update();

   //the CAML query above is equivalent to this after i intercept it in debugging:

 <Where>
<Or>
    <And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Valid_x00e9__x0020_les_x0020_destinataires'   
   /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Envoyer_x0020_vers_x0020_Directeur' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
    </And>
    <Or>
        <And>
          <And>
               <Eq><FieldRef 
  Name='Valid_x00e9__x0020_les_x0020_destinataires' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
               <Eq><FieldRef Name='Envoyer_x0020_vers_x0020_Directeur' 
 /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
          </And>
          <And>
               <Eq><FieldRef Name='R_x00e9_ponse_x0020_Destinataire' 
   /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
               <Eq><FieldRef 
  Name='Fiche_x0020_distribution_x0020_pr_x00e9_par_x00e9_e' /><Value 
  Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
          </And>
        </And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Valid_x00e9__x0020_par_x0020_directeur' />
   <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>
    </Or>
</Or>



  </Where>
```

Comment: I can see you have defined constants for all your fields. Please match the field name constant values with the field names in caml query builder.

Comment: yeah absolutely i did and the generated query below does work perfect in U2U CAML

Comment: so try to only read these constants in your code, do they exists outsite your caml query builder?

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you 100% sure that you run your query against the correct list and not another list accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your CAML list query is not referencing inexistent fields in the primary content type and in the list itself. Remove  the fields or recreate them again.